# What is the difference between these two methods for pausing/resuming threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a multithreaded application which is used to extract data from a website. I wanted to be able to pause and resume multiple threads from the UI. After searching on the web I came to know about two approaches that I can use to control (pause/resume) my threads.

1. Using [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) class.
2. Using [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

---

### What I did:

I have a function named `GetHtml` that simply returns the html of the website. I am just showing the fraction part of this function for brevity.

```
public string GetHtml(string url, bool isProxy = false)
{
    string result = "";
    ExecutionGateway();
    //->> EXTRA CODE FOR FETCHING HTML
    return result;
}
```

I have a function `ControlTasks` used to control threads from UI, below I have explained the `ControlTasks` function using both thread control approaches using the `Monitor` class as well as the `EventWaitHandle` class (I will also briefly explain the working of the function `ExecutionGateway`).

**1. Using the `Monitor` class**

```
private object taskStopper = new object();
public bool ControlTasks(bool isPause)
{
    try
    {
        if (isPause)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(taskStopper);
        }
        else
        {
            Monitor.Exit(taskStopper);
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Instance.WriteLog("ControlTasks:", ex, Logger.LogTypes.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

`ControlTasks` is called from the UI where if `isPause` is true the exclusive lock is used on object `taskStopper` else releases the lock, Now here comes the function `ExecutionGateway` which is used to acquire lock on object `taskStopper` but it does nothing as the code below shows.

```
private void ExecutionGateway()
{
    lock(taskStopper){  }
}
```

In this way all running threads enters waiting state when `isPause` is true in `ControlTasks`  as `taskStopper` is exclusively locked and if `isPause` is false all threads resumes their processing.

**2. Using the `EventWaitHandle` class**

```
private EventWaitHandle handle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
public bool ControlTasks(bool isPause)
{
    try
    {
        if (isPause)
        {
            handle.Reset();
        }
        else
        {
            handle.Set();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Instance.WriteLog("ControlTasks:", ex, Logger.LogTypes.Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code also fundamentally does the same job, where the event state is signaled/non-signaled depending on the `isPause` parameter. Now, the corresponding `ExecutionGateway` method.

```
private void ExecutionGateway()
{
    handle.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

---

### Problem:

1. What is the difference between these two approaches, is one better than the other? Are there any other ways to do this?
2. The main problem I have faced many times is if I use either of the above methods and I have 100 threads; when I pause them, then resume them after 5 or more minutes, the UI starts hanging. The UI is terrifically unresponsive. It gets updated but keeps on hanging and I keep getting the message "Not Responding" at each interval. One thing I want to mention each thread extracts data and notifies the UI about the data fetched through event handling. What could be the reason of this unresponsiveness? Is it a problem with my approach(es)?

Comment: I have experienced this sort of issue before; I have used a combination of `Monitor` and `Semaphore`.  You may want to have a look at `Semaphore`.

Comment: Using approach 1 has a rather significant flaw... Your UI thread can be blocked trying to acquire a lock if you have a lot of contention from your background threads.

Comment: Problem 2 is related to the fact you are blocking the UI thread for a *really* long time. When blocked the UI thread will queue up messages and when it resumes those messages are processed. In general, you should try to avoid blocking the UI thread at all...

Comment: @James but if threads are running then they should have processed all UI mesasges before coming to pause state because threads are on hold so they won't queue up any messages

Answer (score 2):

I think it's always desirable to use a construct that communicates your intent clearly. You want a *signal* to other threads that they should *wait* (i.e. stop doing what they're doing) until you *signal* to them that they can start again. You have one controlling thread (your UI) and potentially many threads doing work and marshalling results back to the UI.

Approach 1 isn't ideal because locks (at least in my experience) are most often used to protect a resource that isn't suitable for use in multi threaded code. For example, writing to a shared field.

Approach 2 makes much more sense, a manual reset event functions like a gate: open the gate and things can pass through, close it and they can't. That's exactly the behaviour you're looking for and I think most developers would understand quite quickly that that's your intent.

As for your second problem, it sounds like you're getting waves of messages clogging the UI. If you stop all 100 of your threads then start them at the same time, there's a good chance they're going to finish their work quite close together and all be trying to send the result of their work to the UI thread. To solve that you could try staggering the work when you restart or use fewer threads. Another option would be to aggregate results and only dispatch the the UI every x seconds - but that's a bit more work.

Answer (score 1):

In Option 1, using the `Monitor` class means that only one thread owns the exclusive lock of the monitor object at a time. This means that of your 100 threads, only 1 is processing at a time, which kind of defeats the purpose of using threads. It also means that your GUI thread has to wait until the current worker thread has finished before it can obtain the lock.

The `ManualResetEvent` is a much better choice as it is used to *signal* between threads, rather than protect against multiple thread access.

I do not know why your GUI is so unresponsive using the second option, but I do not think it is related to your manual reset event. More likely you have a different problem where the GUI thread is getting swamped. You suggest you have 100 threads all firing notification events to the GUI which would seem a likely culprit.

What happens if you debug your app, and just randomly break when your GUI is unresponsive? Doing this many times should show what your GUI thread is up to and where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Montior.Enter is used only through UI and not by any thread. So I think UI is the only thread that owns lock and when resume it releases the lock.

Comment: I did debug and it is kind of difficult to debug multithread code . . . GUI becomes unresposivness when I resume threads after a long time.

Comment: You execution gateway calls `lock` which uses Monitor.Enter internally.

Comment: yes but when ControlTasks function has already been used by the UI for Monitor.Enter then why lock will allow any single thread when the object has already been locked exclusively by UI

Comment: Yes, when the UI calls `Monitor.Enter`, it will own the lock, and all other threads will be blocked by the `lock`. But when the UI releases the lock, only one worker thread can take the exclusive lock at a time.

Comment: Yes correct, but ExecutionGateway method does nothing its blank.

Comment: Ah I see. I assumed you had removed the code for example purposes.

Comment: no, ExecutionGateway is kept empty only, to provide synchronisation